# AFNetworking says "cannot parse response"

Tags: ios8, afnetworking

I am sending a request to server, which is handling the request and responsding. However on my app I am receiving:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo=0x167668d0     
{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://***, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://***/, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot
parse response, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x16731990 "cannot parse
response"
```

Accept field in http request is adequate.

I cannot even see what messege is arriving, because NSHTTPURLResponse object is null.

What can be an issue and in what way I can see what message is coming not using things like wireshark.

Thank You!

Comment: I had the same error. In my case the http-method was not specified on the request object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If iOS cannot parse response, the problem must be in improper format http response from server, even if You are said, that everything is 100% correct, bacause other services communicate with it.

In my case an Android app communicated successfully, because network framework used there was not so restrictive and even if the content-length of http response does not fit the actual length of data, it could read this message, unlike ios.

Use tcpdump to check http communication!

Comment: I was facing same issue, Whts the solution

Comment: any solution for this

Comment: any workaround ?

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem, and the reason is that the API require **GET** http method, and I need pass a parameter, I send it by the following code:

`[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

When I execute the request with **GET** method, it will report the error.

My solution is when the API need **GET** method, the parameter should add on the URL, such as `http://apiserver/api?paramName=paramValue`, when the API method is **POST**, then use the code above, set the HTTPBody for the request object.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue when I tried to call a web method using http GET method instead of http POST. The web service method was expecting POST request not GET. Hope this information will help some one.

Comment: This was the issue for me. I was using AlamoFire for the http request.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using (iOS8 has a problem with this but works in iOS7)

```
NSData *dataToSend = [jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]
```

to send to the server, please make it as per below:

```
NSData *dataToSend = [jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this error because a framework I was using was trying to send URL parameters in a GET request inside a JSON encoded body (instead of as URL-encoded parameters in the URL string as it should have been). That was causing the server send back an "invalid parameters message" which the client couldn't handle and instead aborted mid-request. Switching from body parameters to URL-encoded parameters for GET requests fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First I would ensure you are sending the correct parameters both in the body and the headers. I was receiving this error and after moving one of the parameters from the body into the header I received the correct response.

If there is any documentation for the api make sure you follow it properly.